# How to sum elements of a list encoded as strings with numbers

Tags: python, list, sum

There is a list with duplicate word elements with a number at the end of them. I want to sum the duplicate's numbers, remove the duplicates and print words with sum  of numbers but I don't know how...

Input:

```py
a = ["mango3", "apple2", "kiwi1", "kiwi2", "mango2"]
```

Output:

```
mango5
apple2
kiwi3
```

Comment: You could use a regexp to split the name and number, and build a dictionary {name:total_number}.

Comment: @Swifty I searched a little about regexp now, but because I'm still an amateur, I didn't fully understand it..if it's okay, can you please show me how I can use it and solve my problem?

Comment: Don't store data like that. Maybe you can't control the inputs, but you Can control the outputs. Store the string as a string, but the number as a number, don't store the number In the string. For example, `('apple', 5)` or `{'apple': 5}`

Comment: @MatBailie yes I can't control the way that input is..but you are right I should separate number and word..can you please tell me how I can do it? :((

Comment: @luna did you read Swifty's answer? Have you checked what's in `b`?

Comment: @MatBailie yes yes cuz of my internet problem, my comment sent with a delay 
swifty's answer worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution, first using regex to split the fruit/numbers in your list's elements, building a dictionary of fruit:total_number pairs, and finally recreating a list from the dictionary:

```
import re
a=["mango3","apple2","kiwi1","kiwi2","mango2"]
b={}
for element in a:
    fruit, number = re.findall('\D+',element)[0], re.findall('\d+', element)[0]
    b[fruit] = b.get(fruit,0) + int(number)
c=[fruit + str(number) for fruit,number in b.items()]

print(c)
# ['mango5', 'apple2', 'kiwi3']
```

Explanation about the regex: \d stands for digit, so \d+ will return (in this case where there's only one digit sequence) the longest succession of (at least 1) digits; similarly, \D stands for non-digit.

Note that you could use a single regex with catching groups this way:

```
fruit, number = re.findall('(\D+)(\d+)', element)[0]
```

Comment: Small nitpick: `\d+` matches _all_ continuous digit sequences, not just the longest

Comment: Indeed, my explanation was for this situation, but it wouldn't hold in another.